# Broke Gradle Somehow

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

So somehow I was able to break Gradle while looking around for places to define `PATH`. Anytime I try to run gradle  I get the same error, no matter the command or directory. Here's what I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Users/me/gradle-2/0/bin/gradle
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .Users.me.gradle-2.0.bin.gradle
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

So what the heck is going on now?

Edit: I figured it out! I had set `$GRADLE_OPTS` and for some reason that was screwing everything up

Comment: What OS are you running? What output do you get if you run `echo $PATH` (unix) or `echo %PATH%` (windows)?

Comment: I'm on OSX. I get `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/me/gradle-2.0/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Either this can be some kind of 'space in path' problem (possibly related to a quoting of arguments) or you played with the launching script and the Java invocation so that now it uses some path as a name of executed class.

Comment: How would I check to see if I did those things?

Comment: If you really edited some of the files from Gradle distribution then I'd recommend you to delete it and start with installing Gradle again. Given your question and lack of other details it can be hard to track down what happened and what is wrong.